# My Merge statement is not working properly

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to merge two given table into one into staging table. I run merge statement few times but it did not work properly.
My Stage_Project have FeedbackValue that we could find in lds_project but not in Mch_job. 
What should i do to solve this problem ?
And the next problem is i want to use some if condition in merge statement which i am unable to apply

---

### Merge_statement

```
MERGE INTO  Stage_Project s
    USING (Select project_id,pj_short_desc,pj_actual_start_date,pj_actual_end_date,pj_estimated_end_date,feedback_value from lds_project Union 
    Select  project_id,prj_short_desc pj_short_desc,prj_actual_start_date pj_actual_start_date ,prj_actual_end_date pj_actual_end_a,prj_estimated_end_date pj_estimate_end_date from Mch_job) u
    ON (s.Stage_Project_Key = u.project_id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET
    Stage_Project_Desc   = pj_short_desc,
    Stage_Estimated_End_Date  =pj_actual_start_date,
    Stage_Actual_End_Date   =pj_actual_end_date,
    Stage_FeedbackValue    =feedback_value,
    Stage_Actual_Start_Date =actual_start_date,
    Stage_LdMch_Id    =project_id,
    Stage_Source    =if(leeds)="lds" || if(mch)="mch",
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Stage_Project_Desc,
    Stage_Estimated_End_Date,
    Stage_Actual_End_Date,
    Stage_FeedbackValue,
    Stage_Actual_Start_Date,
    Stage_LdMch_Id,
    Stage_Source)
      VALUES (pj_short_desc,pj_estimated_end_date ,pj_actual_end_date ,feedback_value,pj_actual_start_date,project_id,if(leeds)="lds" || if(mch)="mch");​
```

### Staging table

```
CREATE TABLE Stage_Project(
    Stage_Project_Key    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Stage_Project_Desc    VARCHAR(50),
    Stage_Estimated_End_Date    DATE,
    Stage_Actual_End_Date    DATE,
    Stage_FeedbackValue    INTEGER,
    Stage_Actual_Start_Date    DATE,
    Stage_LdMch_Id    INTEGER,
    Stage_Source    VARCHAR(50),
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Stage_Project".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT    pk_Stage_Project PRIMARY KEY (Stage_Project_Key)
);
```

### Mch_job

```
-- Create a Database table to represent the "Mch_Job" entity.
CREATE TABLE Mch_Job(
    project_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    prj_short_desc    VARCHAR(25),
    prj_required_start_date    DATE,
    prj_estimated_end_date    DATE,
    prj_actual_start_date    DATE,
    prj_actual_end_date    DATE,
    actual_salary    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk1_company_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_consultant_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    supervisor_name    VARCHAR(20),
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Mch_Job".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT    pk_Mch_Job PRIMARY KEY (project_id)
);
```

### lds_project

```
-- Create a Database table to represent the "lds_project" entity.
CREATE TABLE lds_project(
    project_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pj_short_desc    VARCHAR(25),
    pj_required_start_date    DATE,
    pj_estimated_end_date    DATE,
    pj_actual_start_date    DATE,
    pj_actual_end_date    DATE,
    pj_renewal_no    INTEGER,
    pj_rate_day_proj    VARCHAR(1),
    feedback_value    INTEGER,
    actual_salary    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk1_account_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_consultant_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk3_job_role_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "lds_project".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT    pk_lds_project PRIMARY KEY (project_id)
);
```

Comment: Your union in the merge statement needs to have the same number of columns, so to solve the first part of your problem just add a , null to the second part of your union (this gives it the same number of columns as the first select).  I would be looking at either a decode or a case statement rather than the if statement.

Comment: what about the condition in insert statement inside the merge

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were wanting with the IF statement previously, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should work. You can put string literals into a select statement so by adding a different string literal to each part of your Union there is no need for a if statement. It is untested as I do not have an environment where I can create the tables and data but should be close.

```
MERGE INTO  Stage_Project s
    USING (Select project_id,pj_short_desc,pj_actual_start_date,pj_actual_end_date,pj_estimated_end_date,feedback_value, 'lds' as pj_stage_source from lds_project Union 
    Select  project_id,prj_short_desc pj_short_desc,prj_actual_start_date pj_actual_start_date ,prj_actual_end_date pj_actual_end_a,prj_estimated_end_date pj_estimate_end_date, null, 'mch' as pj_stage_source from Mch_job) u
    ON (s.Stage_Project_Key = u.project_id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET
    Stage_Project_Desc   = pj_short_desc,
    Stage_Estimated_End_Date  =pj_actual_start_date,
    Stage_Actual_End_Date   =pj_actual_end_date,
    Stage_FeedbackValue    =feedback_value,
    Stage_Actual_Start_Date =actual_start_date,
    Stage_LdMch_Id    =project_id,
    Stage_Source    = pj_stage_source
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Stage_Project_Desc,
    Stage_Estimated_End_Date,
    Stage_Actual_End_Date,
    Stage_FeedbackValue,
    Stage_Actual_Start_Date,
    Stage_LdMch_Id,
    Stage_Source)
      VALUES (pj_short_desc,pj_estimated_end_date ,pj_actual_end_date ,feedback_value,pj_actual_start_date,project_id,pj_stage_source);​
```

Comment: now it is showing another error called missing expression what shoud i do

Comment: I have edited my answer, there was a extra comma after pj_stage_source in the update section.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In given image the error is missing expression.
And i have also added "==" on select statement because it gave error(missing equal sign)

Comment: i think that this line causes the error:   s.Stage_Source = u.pj_stage_source,     Remove the comma at the end of this line. and in the on clause it should be = and not ==